# extjs: checkbox indent style while not displaying fieldlabel

Tags: extjs, checkbox, indentation

a short question about indent style of checkbox. a new checkbox is created as follows:

```
var newLegendItem = new Ext.form.Checkbox({
    boxLabel: "test",
    name: "test",
    checked:true 
 });
```

in browser, the output checkbox has no indent from left. what I need to do to apply the style of indent?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a margin, adjusting size to taste:

```
var newLegendItem = new Ext.form.Checkbox({
    style: 'margin-left: 30px',
    boxLabel: 'test',
    name: 'test',
    checked: true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to align it inline with other form fields try:

```
hideLabel: false,
fieldLabel: ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to align with other form elements, here's the correct way according to the documentation:

```
hideEmptyLabel: false
```

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-hideEmptyLabel

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer imho, the other proposals are workarounds.